# JavaFx. Создание кнопки от точки до точки

Tags: java, javafx, button

Как в javaFx создать кнопку имеющую начальные координаты X1Y1 и конечные X2Y2, не прибегая к помощи SceneBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Rectangle createRectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
    int min = Math.min(x0, x1);
    int max = Math.max(x0, x1);
    x0 = min;
    x1 = max;

    min = Math.min(y0, y1);
    max = Math.max(y0, y1);
    y0 = min;
    y1 = max;

    return new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1 - x0, y1 - y0);
}
```

Прямоугольник по двум точкам. Оттуда левую верхнюю точку достать и ширину\высоту